# Make grid fill remaining space if there are less columns than specified

Tags: css, css-grid

I am creating a card where it uses grid to displa data. I need to be able to allow a maximum of 8 columns but also allow the grid fill the space available if there is less than 8 columns.

Currently, I'm using grid-template-columns: repeat(8, auto); which fills the space nicely with 8 columns but if I have 6, for example, it leaves a space to the right.

```css
*,
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: #333333;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.gridWrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, auto);
  grid-gap: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.gridItem {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 6px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}

label {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color: #76a8b0;
  font-weight: 100;
}

p {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.cardFooter {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 10px 0 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  background: #333333;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="card" id="card">
  <div class="gridWrapper">
    <div class="gridItem">
      <label for="title">Label</label>
      <p>ContentContentContent</p>
    </div>
    <div class="gridItem">
      <label for="title">Label</label>
      <p>Content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="gridItem">
      <label for="title">Label</label>
      <p>Content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="gridItem">
      <label for="title">Label</label>
      <p>Content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="gridItem">
      <label for="title">Label</label>
      <p>Content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="gridItem">
      <label for="title">Label</label>
      <p>Content</p>
    </div>
    <!-- <div class="gridItem">
          <label for="title">Label</label>
          <p>Content</p>
        </div>
        <div class="gridItem">
          <label for="title">Label</label>
          <p>Content</p> 
        </div> -->
  </div>
</div>
```

I've created a jsfiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/eh7g8Lx1/1/

Comment: Sounds like you want flexbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this with;

> ```
> grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 12%);
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Replace `grid-template-columns: repeat(8, auto);`

line with

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(1rem,1fr));
```

auto-fit value wil solve your problem

Comment: If you're using auto-fit, the content will stretch to fill the entire row width whereas with auto-fill, the browser will allow empty columns to occupy space in the rows

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. This has fixed the spacing issue but not the limit issue. Is there any way to limit the grid to a maximum of 8 columns before it starts a new row?